# pass a Json complex object to a HttpPost Call

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, http-post

So, I'm totally new to web-developing and I have this quite complex object with a lot of fields filled by a JavaScript function.
I need to pass all this data to a C# [HttpPost Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgui2.png).
I used JSON.Stringify to transform all my data in a string and made an [Ajax call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Z0V.png) to pass it to the C# script where there's a class that contains all the expected fields, but once the call starts my input is always Null.

I don't understand if the problem is during the ajax call or inside the httpPost method, can someone help a poor n00b?

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",  
            url: "/playlist",
            data: jsonPlaylist
        })
```

C# method:

```
public class JsonController : Controller
{


    [HttpPost]    
    [Route("playlist")]
    public Playlist getJson([FromBody]string playlist)
    {
        Playlist myPlaylist;
        if (playlist == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            myPlaylist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Playlist>(playlist);
            return myPlaylist;
        }
    }
}
```

object class:

```
 public class Playlist
{
    public struct chunk
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int sizeInBytes { get; set; }
        public float[] times { get; set; }
    }

    public struct chunklist
    {
        public string averagetransfertSpeed { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int sizeInBytes { get; set; }
        public float [] times { get; set; }
        public chunk[] chunks { get; set; }
    }

    public string id { get; set; }
    public string serverId { get; set; }
    public string clientIp { get; set; }
    public string clientRegion { get; set; }
    public string networkcode { get; set; }
    public int sizeInBytes { get; set; }
    public float [] times { get; set; }
    public float [] chunklistsBandwidth { get; set; }
    public chunklist[] chunklists { get; set; }
```

this is the content of the jsonPlaylist:

```
 "id": "playlist.m3u8",
"chunklists": [
    {
        "id": "chunklist-f1-v1-a1.m3u8",
        "times": [
            2.4299999931827188,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "chunks": [
            {
                "id": "seg-1-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    139.26500000525266,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2671480
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-2-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    179.73499998333864,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3336248
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-3-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    228.03500000736676,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 4259704
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-4-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    145.17000000341795,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2716600
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-5-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    104.23500000615604,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1874360
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-6-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    183.2799999974668,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3167800
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-7-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    167.4300000013318,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3098616
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-8-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    159.42499999073334,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2993336
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-9-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    172.01999999815598,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3243000
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-10-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    174.45500000030734,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3116664
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-11-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    149.53999998397194,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2833912
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-12-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    177.34000002383254,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3149752
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-13-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    181.55000000842847,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3363320
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-14-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    188.6649999942165,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3570872
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-15-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    151.58999999403022,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2854968
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-16-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    140.3850000060629,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2475960
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-17-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    213.38999998988584,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3847608
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-18-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    15.46500000404194,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 250040
            }
        ],
        "sizeInBytes": 757,
        "averageTransfertSpeed": "146.3282"
    },
    {
        "id": "chunklist-f2-v1-a1.m3u8",
        "times": [
            0.7949999999254942,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "chunks": [
            {
                "id": "seg-1-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    88.35000000544824,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1600632
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-2-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    97.8950000135228,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1829240
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-3-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    126.09999999403954,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2313528
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-4-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    78.01999998628162,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1504376
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-5-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    62.944999983301386,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1185528
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-6-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    98.8200000138022,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1838264
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-7-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    95.55499997804873,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1745016
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-8-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    96.30499998456798,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1723960
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-9-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    99.33500000624917,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1811192
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-10-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    117.35500002396293,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1820216
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-11-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    93.27000001212582,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1675832
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-12-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    106.61000001709908,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1811192
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-13-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    123.58500002301298,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1922488
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-14-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    106.47500000777654,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2039800
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-15-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    94.94999999878928,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1615672
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-16-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    81.07499999459833,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1411128
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-17-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    125.03000002470799,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2229304
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-18-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    7.4099999910686165,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 132728
            }
        ],
        "sizeInBytes": 757,
        "averageTransfertSpeed": "142.9368"
    },
    {
        "id": "chunklist-f3-v1-a1.m3u8",
        "times": [
            1.6149999864865094,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "chunks": [
            {
                "id": "seg-1-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    54.34500001138076,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1035128
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-2-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    66.39999998151325,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1140408
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-3-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    83.42999999877065,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1480312
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-4-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    56.314999994356185,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 996024
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-5-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    43.1549999921117,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 773432
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-6-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    64.38500000513159,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1167480
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-7-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    59.35500000487082,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1113336
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-8-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    63.7249999854248,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1119352
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-9-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    63.30500001786277,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1158456
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-10-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    65.75000000884756,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1161464
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-11-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    58.2400000130292,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1083256
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-12-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    61.17500000982545,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1161464
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-13-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    65.2399999962654,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1206584
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-14-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    73.72499999473803,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1317880
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-15-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    57.865000009769574,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1044152
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-16-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    54.42500000935979,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 908792
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-17-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    82.24999997764826,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1441208
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-18-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    4.824999981792644,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 78584
            }
        ],
        "sizeInBytes": 757,
        "averageTransfertSpeed": "143.3341"
    },
    {
        "id": "chunklist-f4-v1-a1.m3u8",
        "times": [
            1.7949999892152846,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "chunks": [
            {
                "id": "seg-1-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    33.18499997840263,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 568888
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-2-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    52.08000002312474,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 650104
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-3-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    47.10500000510365,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 797496
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-4-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    31.75500000361353,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 565880
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-5-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    25.475000002188608,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 460600
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-6-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    34.23000001930632,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 650104
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-7-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    32.765000010840595,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 620024
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-8-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    35.14500000164844,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 617016
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-9-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    34.48000000207685,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 641080
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-10-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    36.075000010896474,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 641080
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-11-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    35.514999995939434,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 629048
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-12-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    35.23999999742955,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 653112
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-13-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    38.14999997848645,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 662136
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-14-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    41.41999999410473,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 725304
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-15-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    31.739999976707622,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 568888
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-16-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    29.27500000805594,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 535800
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-17-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    45.56999998749234,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 785464
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-18-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    3.015000023879111,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 45496
            }
        ],
        "sizeInBytes": 757,
        "averageTransfertSpeed": "139.5362"
    }
],
"times": [
    3.5700000007636845,
    0,
    0
],
"serverId": "servername",
"clientIp": "ip",
"clientRegion": "region",
"networkCode": " code",
"chunklistsBandwidth": [
    2385338,
    1351592,
    855454,
    461917
],
"sizeInBytes": 572
```

}

Comment: can you please post the json and the C# method ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add the missing information to your question. Otherwise we cannot even take a guess about your problem.

Comment: It would be easier if we could see your controller action and your js

Comment: I edited and uploaded a screen of the object, and the other two hyperlinks are the image of the ajax call and the c# method, first time using stackoverflow sorry if it's not the best presentation

Comment: Re:Edit I added the code directly

Comment: @Peru can you also add a JSON example of the object you are posting?

Comment: @BrunoXavier I added the content of the stringified playlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try to model bind the object directly like this:

```
public class JsonController : Controller
{


    [HttpPost]    
    [Route("playlist")]
    public Playlist getJson([FromBody]Playlist playlist)
    {
        if (playlist == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Also, make sure to set your content type correctly:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/playlist",
            data: jsonPlaylist
        })
```

With a JSON like this:

```
 {
 "id": "playlist.m3u8",
"chunklists": [
    {
        "id": "chunklist-f1-v1-a1.m3u8",
        "times": [
            2.4299999931827188,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "chunks": [
            {
                "id": "seg-1-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    139.26500000525266,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2671480
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-2-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    179.73499998333864,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3336248
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-3-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    228.03500000736676,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 4259704
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-4-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    145.17000000341795,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2716600
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-5-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    104.23500000615604,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1874360
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-6-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    183.2799999974668,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3167800
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-7-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    167.4300000013318,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3098616
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-8-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    159.42499999073334,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2993336
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-9-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    172.01999999815598,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3243000
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-10-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    174.45500000030734,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3116664
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-11-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    149.53999998397194,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2833912
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-12-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    177.34000002383254,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3149752
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-13-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    181.55000000842847,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3363320
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-14-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    188.6649999942165,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3570872
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-15-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    151.58999999403022,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2854968
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-16-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    140.3850000060629,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2475960
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-17-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    213.38999998988584,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 3847608
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-18-f1-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    15.46500000404194,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 250040
            }
        ],
        "sizeInBytes": 757,
        "averageTransfertSpeed": "146.3282"
    },
    {
        "id": "chunklist-f2-v1-a1.m3u8",
        "times": [
            0.7949999999254942,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "chunks": [
            {
                "id": "seg-1-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    88.35000000544824,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1600632
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-2-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    97.8950000135228,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1829240
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-3-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    126.09999999403954,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2313528
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-4-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    78.01999998628162,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1504376
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-5-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    62.944999983301386,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1185528
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-6-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    98.8200000138022,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1838264
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-7-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    95.55499997804873,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1745016
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-8-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    96.30499998456798,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1723960
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-9-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    99.33500000624917,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1811192
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-10-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    117.35500002396293,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1820216
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-11-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    93.27000001212582,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1675832
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-12-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    106.61000001709908,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1811192
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-13-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    123.58500002301298,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1922488
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-14-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    106.47500000777654,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2039800
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-15-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    94.94999999878928,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1615672
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-16-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    81.07499999459833,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1411128
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-17-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    125.03000002470799,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 2229304
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-18-f2-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    7.4099999910686165,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 132728
            }
        ],
        "sizeInBytes": 757,
        "averageTransfertSpeed": "142.9368"
    },
    {
        "id": "chunklist-f3-v1-a1.m3u8",
        "times": [
            1.6149999864865094,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "chunks": [
            {
                "id": "seg-1-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    54.34500001138076,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1035128
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-2-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    66.39999998151325,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1140408
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-3-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    83.42999999877065,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1480312
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-4-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    56.314999994356185,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 996024
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-5-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    43.1549999921117,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 773432
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-6-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    64.38500000513159,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1167480
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-7-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    59.35500000487082,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1113336
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-8-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    63.7249999854248,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1119352
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-9-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    63.30500001786277,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1158456
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-10-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    65.75000000884756,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1161464
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-11-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    58.2400000130292,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1083256
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-12-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    61.17500000982545,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1161464
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-13-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    65.2399999962654,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1206584
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-14-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    73.72499999473803,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1317880
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-15-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    57.865000009769574,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1044152
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-16-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    54.42500000935979,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 908792
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-17-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    82.24999997764826,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 1441208
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-18-f3-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    4.824999981792644,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 78584
            }
        ],
        "sizeInBytes": 757,
        "averageTransfertSpeed": "143.3341"
    },
    {
        "id": "chunklist-f4-v1-a1.m3u8",
        "times": [
            1.7949999892152846,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "chunks": [
            {
                "id": "seg-1-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    33.18499997840263,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 568888
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-2-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    52.08000002312474,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 650104
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-3-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    47.10500000510365,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 797496
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-4-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    31.75500000361353,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 565880
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-5-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    25.475000002188608,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 460600
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-6-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    34.23000001930632,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 650104
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-7-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    32.765000010840595,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 620024
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-8-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    35.14500000164844,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 617016
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-9-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    34.48000000207685,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 641080
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-10-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    36.075000010896474,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 641080
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-11-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    35.514999995939434,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 629048
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-12-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    35.23999999742955,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 653112
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-13-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    38.14999997848645,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 662136
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-14-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    41.41999999410473,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 725304
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-15-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    31.739999976707622,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 568888
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-16-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    29.27500000805594,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 535800
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-17-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    45.56999998749234,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 785464
            },
            {
                "id": "seg-18-f4-v1-a1.ts",
                "times": [
                    3.015000023879111,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "sizeInBytes": 45496
            }
        ],
        "sizeInBytes": 757,
        "averageTransfertSpeed": "139.5362"
    }
],
"times": [
    3.5700000007636845,
    0,
    0
],
"serverId": "servername",
"clientIp": "ip",
"clientRegion": "region",
"networkCode": " code",
"chunklistsBandwidth": [
    2385338,
    1351592,
    855454,
    461917
],
"sizeInBytes": 572
}
```

This is what Postman looks like:

[image]

And this is what I'm seeing on VS:
[image]

Comment: I tried but calling Postman it gives back 415 unsupported media type

Comment: @Peru I just did a quick test on VS with Postman, using the exact same code I posted and I get it serialized in the controller. Are you sure you are posting the correct JSON? I had to add the opening and closing brackets on the one in your question

Comment: Yes I had to remove the opening/closing brackets on VScode for making it readable otherwise it would be a long single line, but the object itself actually has them.

The json i posted is the debug output of the line "let jsonPlaylist = JSON.stringify(playlist)", so I do not understand why it wouldn't work, Am I writing something bad maybe?

Comment: @Peru if you get the JSON I just posted, with the action change and put it on Postman as a POST with a Raw body (JSON), do you get a 415 still?

Comment: I copy-pasted your json and put it as content of jsonPlaylist variable and called a POST with raw-JSON body on postman but yes, the error is always 415

can it be som header problem? I added to the c# this:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

Comment: @Peru can you check my edit and see if you are doing exactly that?

Comment: I checked and now the object is correctly seen from the method (debugging getJson shows all the data), but still postman is giving me answer 415 and nothing displayed inside the body.

I cheked and in Postman is selected raw and JSON (it's only JSON and not JSON(json/application) like in your screenshot, idk it is a problem?)

Comment: Go to the headers tab and manually change the Content-Type to application/json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216270/discussion-between-peru-and-bruno-xavier).